# How can I force GWT widget to update?

Tags: gwt

I have GWT widget(FlexTable) on my page. When I set some rows on it to visible false, it will be not updated. How can I force it to update?

Comment: Paste the code you're using to hide the row. You must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

GWT hides by adding "display:none" as inline style to the element be it table row or anything else. Look in the rendered HTML and see if this style is applied, if not paste the code as mabn pointed out.

If hiding does not happen, the usual reason is there must be some other piece of code that is invoked by your refresh/update on the Flextable that re-renders back / re-displays the hidden rows. Service callbacks often do this, due to the asynchronous nature of the callback, code in the callback that usually renders a table full of data, often does so unexpectedly.

Search for the code that populates your table (this is usually inside a callback) and check if it's invoked after you have hidden some rows.