# How to force widget to redraw himself

Tags: gwt

I've just started to work with gwt, and I'm trying to solve following task:
I have two classes Month and Year that extand composite. And in my implementation class I have

```
UiField(provided = true)
Composite composite;

Month month;

Year year;
...
//Constructor
@Inject
MyClassImpl(){
  month = new Month();
  year = new Year();
  composite = month;
}

updateComposite(){
  composite = year;
  logger.fine("composite = " + composite);
}
```

My problem is when I call updateComposite() method I see on console that it's updated but it's not redraw on the screen. It look's like the answer to my question is very simple, but I didn't managed to find it. I looked here [How can I force GWT widget to update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688165/how-can-i-force-gwt-widget-to-update) and some other places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're changing the value if a field in your class (which will translate to a property if a JS object), you're not swapping the components into the DOM.

You need to put the new value in place of the old one in the DOM. The way you'd do this depends a lot on your ui.xml though. One possibility would be to use a SimplePanel instead in the ui.xml and use setWidget to set the appropriate widget to be shown.

Comment: Thanks, I looked through setWidget source code and saw that attaching widget to DOM tree was the thing I forgot to do.